# Find constant a and b for which $F(a,b) = \int_0^\pi \{ \sin x - (ax^2 + bx)\}^2 dx$ is a minimum.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, definite-integrals, lagrange-multiplier

I am not sure how to do this problem. I tried to look up similar problems but was unsuccessful at finding any. I would appreciate if someone could show me how to solve this problem. Here's the question again :

Find constants a and b for which $F(a,b) =\int_0^\pi \{ \sin x - (ax^2 + bx)\}^2 dx$ is a minimum. (You may use Wolfram or other tools to integrate)

Comment: Do you know Leibniz's theorem about differentiating through the integral? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule .

Comment: No I am not familiar with that theorem, we didn't go over it in class

Comment: then square it and solve the integral

Comment: Right -- this IS a problem where you can just do it, esp if you're allowed to use an automated integration tool. So write out $F(a, b)$ explicitly (it'll be something of a mess) and then to find the min, find a place where the gradient of $F$ is zero.

Comment: @JohnHughes So basically I need to solve the integral first and THEN find the min?

Comment: So when I used Wolfram to integrate from 0 to pi, I get a very complicated constant, how would I find the gradient from that? this is what I get : (pi^5a^2)/5 + a((pi^4b)/2 - 2pi^2 + 8) +1/6pi(2pi^2b^2 - 12b +3)

Comment: It seems straightforward to me to differentiate that to find the gradient. It is, after all, a quadratic in $a$ and $b$, and I'm hoping you know how to differentiate a quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

The function is
$$F(a,b) = {{10\,\pi^3\,b^2+\left(15\,\pi^4\,a-60\,\pi\right)\,b+6\,\pi^5\,a^2
 +\left(240-60\,\pi^2\right)\,a+15\,\pi}\over{30}}.$$
And the critical points are given by:
$$\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial a} = {{15\,\pi^4\,b+12\,\pi^5\,a-60\,\pi^2+240}\over{30}} = 0,$$

$$\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial b} = {{20\,\pi^3\,b+15\,\pi^4\,a-60\,\pi}\over{30}} = 0,$$
that is a $2\times 2$ linear system.